# prestashop-1.7 new module discover

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm learning the basics of module development in Prestashop (1.7.4.3). I'm having problem with new module installation in the system.
This is my file for the new module, located at: `modules/mymodule/mymodule.php`:

```
<?php 
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodule';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.6',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_
        ];
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        // parent::install();
        // this code is executed

        if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME')) {
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
        }

    }

    public function install()
    {
        // die('install method');
        // this code is never executed

        return parent::install();
    }
}
```

Standard module template, as you can see. When I enter the modules tab in the BackOffice, I don't see my module on the available modules list.

While debugging, I've tried putting the install function call inside the __constructor() body, and it worked. I don't see a reason why __construct() is being executed and install() would not.

Permissions on modules folder are set to 777. Prestashop is installed in a Windows host/ Ubuntu guest Virtual Box shared folder.

**Edit**: I installed Prestashop 1.6.1.22 (in the same environment as PS 1.7) and the above-mentioned module worked like a a charm from the get-go. Seems like an issue with PS 1.7

Comment: I copied exactly what you pasted and worked fine!

Comment: Just to prove to myself I'm not making some basic mistake, I installed a fresh instance of Prestashop on XAMPP localhost. Then I placed the above-mentioned file at `modules/mymodule/mymodule.php`.
Then I went to Backoofice -> Modules -> Modules & Services.
I should be seeing 'My module' under 'installed modules', right? 
Well, it isn't there.

Comment: What's the php version you are running?, because the short array used in the `ps_versions_compliancy` is available since php 5.4+

Comment: I tried: php-5.6 on xampp and php-7.0 on ubuntu

Comment: Your module should be listed in the tab Modules -> Modules & Services -> Selection until you have installed it and only then in the Installed modules tab. So check it out, probably it's the only problem